# Using Ember.js with Handlebars.js View in Jade

Tags: ember.js, pug, handlebars.js

I am trying to add an ember view using handlebars.js in jade.  When I use this code

```
script(type='text/x-handlebars') 
    {{view App.LoginView}} 
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="username" placeholder="Enter your username"}}
```

it renders it as:

```
<div id="ember194" class="ember-view"></div>
<input id="ember204" class="ember-view ember-text-field" placeholder="Enter your username" type="text">
```

I can't seem to get the textfield to be wrapped within the view.  I am wondering if there is a trick to be able to use handlebars correctly within a jade template.

The desired result that I want is:

```
<div id="ember194" class="ember-view">
    <input id="ember204" class="ember-view ember-text-field" placeholder="Enter your username" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
script(type='text/x-handlebars') 
    {{#view App.LoginView}} 
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="username" placeholder="Enter your username"}}
    {{/view}}
```

Jade saves you from HTML closing tags but the handlebars block must be intact, and what you're asking for requires the `Ember.TextField` to be inside a `{{#view}}` block.

[Edit] FYI check out http://emblemjs.com/

Comment: Thanks, this is an oldie but a goodie.  Was just getting started on the ember world.  Seems like many moons ago.